# InnerHTML добавление в начало

Tags: javascript

Можно как то что бы innerHTML добавлял текст в начало, а не конец

Answer (score 4):

innerHTML это свойство типа строка а не метод. в чем сложность ? делайте

```
 element.innerHTML=text+element.innerHTML;
```

Comment: я что-то не понимаю ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/4L7eU/

Comment: Да что-то у меня расширение тупит. Обновил,но выводиться старый код